# Extract Date Ranges where data is missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Given dummy data frame as below:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
|   Start_Date    |    End_Date     | Price |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
| 01/01/2021 0:00 | 01/01/2021 0:59 |    10 |
| 01/01/2021 0:01 | 01/01/2021 0:01 |    20 |
| 01/01/2021 0:02 | 01/01/2021 0:02 |    24 |
| 01/01/2021 0:03 | 01/01/2021 0:03 |    23 |
| 01/01/2021 0:07 | 01/01/2021 0:07 |    34 |
| 01/01/2021 0:08 | 01/01/2021 0:08 |    37 |
| 01/01/2021 0:10 | 01/01/2021 0:10 |    21 |
| 01/01/2021 0:12 | 01/01/2021 0:12 |    22 |
| 01/01/2021 0:14 | 01/01/2021 0:14 |    56 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

The above data frame can be generated using code below:

```
data = {'Start_Date':['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:01:00', '2021-01-01 00:02:00', '2021-01-01 00:03:00', '2021-01-01 00:07:00',
                      '2021-01-01 00:08:00', '2021-01-01 00:10:00', '2021-01-01 00:12:00', '2021-01-01 00:14:00'],
        'End_Date':['2021-01-01 00:59:00', '2021-01-01 00:01:59', '2021-01-01 00:02:59', '2021-01-01 00:03:59', '2021-01-01 00:07:59',
                      '2021-01-01 00:08:59', '2021-01-01 00:10:59', '2021-01-01 00:12:59', '2021-01-01 00:14:59'],
        'Avg_Price':[10, 20, 24, 23, 34, 37, 21, 22, 56]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start_Date'])
df1['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End_Date'])
```

It can be seen that there are date ranges where data is missing. Missing ranges can be seen in data frame below:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|     Start_Date      |      End_Date       | Price |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 00:59:00 | 10    |
| 2021-01-01 00:01:00 | 2021-01-01 00:01:59 | 20    |
| 2021-01-01 00:02:00 | 2021-01-01 00:02:59 | 24    |
| 2021-01-01 00:03:00 | 2021-01-01 00:03:59 | 23    |
| 2021-01-01 00:04:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:06:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:07:00 | 2021-01-01 00:07:59 | 34    |
| 2021-01-01 00:08:00 | 2021-01-01 00:08:59 | 37    |
| 2021-01-01 00:09:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:10:00 | 2021-01-01 00:10:59 | 21    |
| 2021-01-01 00:11:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:12:00 | 2021-01-01 00:12:59 | 22    |
| 2021-01-01 00:13:00 | NaT                 | NaN   |
| 2021-01-01 00:14:00 | 2021-01-01 00:14:59 | 56    |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Above can be generated using code below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:14:00', freq='min'))
df2 = df2.join(df1.set_index('Start_Date'))
```

I want list of lists to get dates ranges where data is missing.

**Expected Output**

```
result = [['2021-01-01 00:04:00','2021-01-01 00:06:00'], ['2021-01-01 00:09:00','2021-01-01 00:09:00'],
['2021-01-01 00:11:00', '2021-01-01 00:11:00'], ['2021-01-01 00:13:00','2021-01-01 00:13:00']]
```

What would be elegant way to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create groups by consecutive `NaN`s by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter only `NaN`s by invert by `~` and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `min` and `max`, last convert to strings and then to nested `list`s:

```
m = df2['End_Date'].notna()

L = (df2.index.to_series()
        .groupby(m.cumsum()[~m])
        .agg(['min','max'])
        .astype(str)
        .to_numpy()
        .tolist())
print (L)
[['2021-01-01 00:04:00', '2021-01-01 00:06:00'], 
 ['2021-01-01 00:09:00', '2021-01-01 00:09:00'],
 ['2021-01-01 00:11:00', '2021-01-01 00:11:00'], 
 ['2021-01-01 00:13:00', '2021-01-01 00:13:00']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of null checking, combined with `np.split` and a list comprehension works on the sample data shared :

```py
boolean = df2.End_Date.isna().cumsum()
# get position count for each null end
val = boolean[boolean.gt(0) & boolean.duplicated()].array.unique()

nulls = df2.index[df2.End_Date.isna()]


[[ent[0], ent[-1]] 
 for ent in np.split(nulls, val) 
if ent.size > 0]
 
[[Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:04:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:06:00')],
 [Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:09:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:09:00')],
 [Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:11:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:11:00')],
 [Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:13:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:13:00')]]


# if you prefer string form :
[[str(ent[0]), str(ent[-1])] 
 for ent in np.split(nulls, val) 
if ent.size > 0]
 
[['2021-01-01 00:04:00', '2021-01-01 00:06:00'],
 ['2021-01-01 00:09:00', '2021-01-01 00:09:00'],
 ['2021-01-01 00:11:00', '2021-01-01 00:11:00'],
 ['2021-01-01 00:13:00', '2021-01-01 00:13:00']]
```